# How to kill the current process with java 9

Tags: java-9, processhandle

I have tried with both `destroy` and `destroyForcibly` using the below code -

```
ProcessHandle currentProcess = ProcessHandle.current();
System.out.println("current process id:"+currentProcess.getPid());
currentProcess.destroyForcibly();
```

but getting an exception in both cases as

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: destroy of
>   current process not allowed   at
>   java.base/java.lang.ProcessHandleImpl.destroyProcess(ProcessHandleImpl.java:308)
>     at
>   java.base/java.lang.ProcessHandleImpl.destroyForcibly(ProcessHandleImpl.java:331)
>     at util.CurrentProcess.main(CurrentProcess.java:18)

Comment: Why don't you just use `System.exit`?

Comment: Did your process even start to kill? :/

Comment: Holger, I just want to see how I can kill process with java 9  using process library.
Minigeek, Process started  and it's up

Comment: @SudarsanaKasireddy process is supposed to be killed by destroy method..this will work for processbuilder for sure... I don't know abt processhandle :/ and Btw be aware that if the process that you invoke creates new sub-processes, those may not be terminated (seehttp://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4770092).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Javadoc on `ProcessHandle::current`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html#current--) says:

> Returns a `ProcessHandle` for the current process. The `ProcessHandle` cannot be used to destroy the current process, use [`System.exit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit-int-) instead.